# How to install gradle plugin in RAD websphere?

Tags: gradle, websphere, websphere-liberty, gradle-plugin, rad

Using IDE RAD WebSphere. Need to install gradle plugin to use in our project.

normally in eclipse I have used with eclipse market place and choose the integration buildship gradle . but here no option as like that. how to install gradle plugin to RAD websphere ? kindly help.

tried in google cant find any related answer.

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.attachCallerThreadStackTrace(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultToolingClient.executeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultModelRequest.executeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository$1.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.getFromCache(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.fetchGradleBuildStructure(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.fetchGradleBuildStructure(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.runToolingApiJobInWorkspace(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: Could not receive a message from the daemon.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.produceModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildInvocationsAdapterProducer.produceModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NonCancellableConsumerConnectionAdapter.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:60425'.
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.io.ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.Message$ExceptionReplacingObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.Message.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.DefaultMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do it the manual way, described here:
https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Finstallation%2Fupdatesite_3.5.html

The install sites for BuildShip (the gradle plugin) are here:
https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/docs/user/Installation.md#installing-from-eclipseorg-update-site

Comment: Hi marks,Thanks for you response, I tried that solution as well it keep installing for very long time and not finishing ... it installing for gradle.toolingapi    for ever  I used below url for build ship as I using websphere RAD 8.5 and Java 1.6 is this correct one? http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e46/releases/1.0

Comment: It looks like that version of the plugin is meant for Eclipse 4.6, where RAD 8.5 is built on Eclipse 3.6. Try this link instead:  
Helios (3.6)  http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e36/releases/1.0

Also, consider moving up Java versions, since Java 6 is out of support :-)

Comment: when I tried that one I getting the below error:An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
session context was:(profile=bootProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
Error reading signed content.
The file "D:\IBM_new\SDP_5\p2\cic.p2.cache.location\plugins\com.google.gson_2.2.4.v201311231704.jar" does not exist

Comment: It looks like the gson jar is probably missing or corrupted. First thing I would try is a fresh install of RAD 8.5 to see if it installs there.

Comment: Hi Mark, It works thanks, but after installation while create gradle project I getting below exception...org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-bin.zip'.
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(Unknown Source)
 at

Comment: please help on it

Comment: And I too tried while creating gradle project with 1.11 version of gradle distribution , after some time of processing it shows the below error org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution

Comment: Can you post the full stack for the exception?

Comment: Looks like gradle is having issues communicating with the daemon. Have you tried restarting it: gradle --stop ?

Comment: what is this exception is about Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: Could not receive a message from the daemon.

Comment: any idea please for this issue?

Comment: You could try building without the daemon to see if that works/or shows more about the issue: ./gradlew --no-daemon